# Mail with empty variables if using $_POST to check for button state

Tags: php, forms, email, variables, post

I have a simple form for selecting from some items (food) on my index.php page. This page sends the info to "order.php" by POST. On the "order.php" page I can echo the items picked on the previous page, but If I try to mail them forward I get an empty mail.

If I use another if condition "($x > 0)", I get the contend by mail just fine. What is wrong with: "if (isset($_POST['confirm']))" ??

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="css/template.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>Ordered Food</title>
</head>
<body>

Your order the following:

<table id="order_table">
<tbody>

<?php
$items = '';
$x = 1;

foreach($_POST as $key => $value){ 
    if ($value == 0) {
        continue;   
}
    $items .= "$key: $value\n";
    echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td class='value'>$value</td></tr>";     
}

// if( $x > 0 )  this was working
if (isset($_POST['confirm'])) {
$message = $items;
mail("v***@yahoo.com", $subject, $message, $headers); 
echo "<p>Thanks for your order!</p>";
    }
// }
?>

</tbody>
</table>

<p>
<form method="post">
<input name="confirm" type="submit" value="Send Order">
</form>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The previous page, in case if it is needed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Alm Chalet Menu</title>
<link href="css/template.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/template.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="logo"><img src="images/logo.png"/></div>

<div class="intro_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</div>

<div class="category">
<p class="categ_title">Biologische Säfte</p>
<div class="form_style">

<form method="post" action="order.php">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="number" name="orange" min="0" value="0" class="count_style" id="qty">
<span>Orange</span>
</td>
<td>
<div class="field"><input type="number" name="multivitamine" min="0" value="0" class="count_style">Multivitamine</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="number" name="grapefruit" min="0" value="0" class="count_style" id="qty">
<span>Grapefruit</span>
</td>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Menu" />
</form>
</div>
</div>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

===========

Updated code part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="css/template.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>Ordered Food</title>
</head>
<body>

Your order the following:

<table id="order_table">
<tbody>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['confirm'])) {

$items = '';


foreach($_POST as $key => $value){ 
    if ($value == 0) {
        continue;   
}
    $items .= "$key: $value\n";
    echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td class='value'>$value</td></tr>";     
}

$headers ="xxx";
$message = $items;
mail("foo@yahoo.com", $subject, $message, $headers); 
echo "<p>Thanks for your order!</p>";
}
?>

</tbody>
</table>

<p>
<form method="post">
<input name="confirm" type="submit" value="Send Order">
</form>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have no headers to include, `$headers` is presently only a (empty) variable, but nothing has been set/assigned to it. I would also place `if (isset($_POST['confirm'])) {` above `$items = '';` the way you have it now, nothing else is being used, because of the placement of the conditional statement. Everything else outside of it (`if (isset($_POST['confirm']))`), is being ignored.

Comment: @Fred-ii- added '$headers ="xxx";' and now got "xxx" i my inbox, but "message" still empty. If I echo "$items" inside the condition is empty too. What am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: Re-read my comment again, *slowly & carefully*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- oups...right...reading through...

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have modified the code, but "message" is still empty. Please see the updated code above (on bottom of original post)....thanks. :(

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake about the conditional statement, I am testing the code now.

Comment: This is a 2 stage form you're building? You will need to store the previously submitted `$items` into `$_SESSION`. When the user clicks `confirm`, all the previously entered stuff is lost, and the _only_ thing existing in `$_POST` will be `confirm`.

Comment: That's what I was also thinking about @MichaelBerkowski (sessions)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - I have tried $_SESSIONS too. But no difference. The values are present in "order.php". If I remove the "if condition"  all values are sent just fine by mail, on first page load. But as I put it back, as Fred -ii- said, it ignores everything else outside the condition...:(

Comment: @EdmondTamas Hold on, I'll write a full answer describing what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are building a two-stage form, you need to keep in mind that PHP is essentially stateless between HTTP requests from the browser. Unless you explicitly store values in `$_SESSION` for later use, they will *not* be present on a subsequent page load. Clicking `confirm` counts as a subsequent page load.

So the easiest solution is to simply store the string you constructed as `$items` into `$_SESSION` and read from it when processing the confirmation.

This requires no changes to your initial form. However, you'll need a few modifications on `order.php`.

The three sections that follow should more or less replace the code you had in your *original* `order.php` at the top of your question.

First, initialize `session_start()`:

```
<?php
// At the *top* of order.php, after <?php but before *anything else*
// It must come before the HTML output...
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="css/template.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>Ordered Food</title>
</head>
<body>
// etc....
```

Then when you receive the initial form submission, check for the presence of `$_POST['submit']` and store the received key/value pairs for later.

```
<?php
$items = '';
$x = 1;

// Only if this was the original submission ($_POST['submit'] is set)
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {    
  foreach($_POST as $key => $value){ 
      if ($value == 0) {
          continue;   
      }
      $items .= "$key: $value\n";
      echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td class='value'>$value</td></tr>";

      // Save the $items string into $_SESSION
      // There are other, possibly better, ways to handle this, like storing the actual
      // $_POST array or a subset, but this is simplest given your existing code
      $_SESSION['items'] = $items;
  }
}
```

Okay, now your values will persist when the user clicks `confirm`. Let's handle that in the last section to change:

```
<!-- close the HTML table before doing this, not after as in your original... -->
</tbody>
</table>

<?php
// If confirm was clicked *and* the items are stored in $_SESSION
// send the email
if (isset($_POST['confirm']) && isset($_SESSION['items'])) {
  // Instead of $items, here read from the session value $_SESSION['items']
  $message = $_SESSION['items'];
  mail("v***@yahoo.com", $subject, $message, $headers); 
  echo "<p>Thanks for your order!</p>";

  // Then unset the value from $_SESSION
  unset($_SESSION['items']);
}
// But only display the confirmation form if confirm wasn't clicked yet!
// Otherwise they'll see the form again after confirmation, which is untidy
else {
?>
<p>
<form method="post">
<input name="confirm" type="submit" value="Send Order">
</form>
</p>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Slight typo Michael, in `$_SESSION['itmems'])` => `$_SESSION['items'])`

Comment: @Fred-ii- just noticed as you were commenting, thanks ,along with another issue of still reading from `$items` instead of `$_SESSION['items']`

Comment: You're welcome. (I mentioned it just in case OP copied it right away).

Comment: Another thing Michael. I tested your answer, it worked but that was only when I added `session_start();` above `$items = '';` which is missing; just thought I would let you know. Other than that, worked beautifully. Unless, the 3 bodies of code are to go together? If so, it will throw a parse error because of the missing `?>` under the last 2 braces after `$_SESSION['items'] = $items;`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did have `session_start()` before the `<!DOCTYPE>`. I didn't intend the 3 sections to run together, just to replace their corresponding sections in the original. I'll clarify - thanks for your input.

Comment: You're welcome Michael. I was able to figure it out, am just not sure if the OP would have trouble or not. +1 ;-) btw

Comment: @Michael Berkowski - thanks for the great explanations and sample, of course thanks for Fred -ii- as well for the corrections!! I have tested on my phone because I left my place but it seem to be OK! Can't wait to put it to use...:)